# Call to HttpClient.PostAsync() cancelling task with system.threading.tasks.task.throwifexceptional exception

Tags: .net, multithreading, cross-domain, httpclient

I am trying to create a PDF from the HTML. This part is done in a PHP file with a third party tool. When tested in the development server is working fine. But while moved to **Live** server, the call to **HttpClient.PostAsync** is throwing below error.

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1.get_Result()
>   at myProject.mymethod(Int32[] myIds) in path\MyClass.cs:line

My Code:

```
public static void TestFunction()
{
    try
    {
        string htmlToRender = "My Test Data";

        // Convert the string into HttpContent object
        HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(htmlToRender);

        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            formData.Add(stringContent, "htmlToRender");

            Task<System.IO.Stream> response = GetHttpContent(formData);

            return response.Result;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "innerExc" + ex.InnerException);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private async Task<Stream> GetHttpContent(MultipartFormDataContent ahttpContent)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                        "--My request uri to the PHP file--", ahttpContent);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Upgraded my **.Net framework version to 4.5**

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The above task cancellation error message i added.

Comment: You only added a partial stack-trace. That doesn't help.

Comment: Actually its not even logging anything to event log, the page is getting crashed with the above error message and is followed by my set of function and class information. Error is on the postasync call.

Comment: @SunilKBehera Have you got this resolved? I need guidance as I am facing same issue.